# Bootstrap accordion pluses minuses issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I do not understand why displaying all `-` rather than `+` on panel-header

After clicking on panel it converts all  `-`  to  `+`.

But it's not for the first time I load the page.

**CSS**:

```
.panel-heading a:after {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\2212"; /* Plus */
    float: right;
    color: #ebebeb;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:12px;
    font-size:12px;
    border-radius:6px;
}

.panel-heading a.collapsed:after {
    content: "\2b";
}
```

Full Code here :
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/31734/)

What i did wrong?

Comment: why are you setting the same css for different classes, intead you just create one class and target all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `collapsed` class to all your `a` tags having `data-toggle="collapse"`. because, on run time, when user clicks on a `collapse` component, `Bootstrap` appends `collapsed` class inside the `DOM` at the said location.

```css
.agronomija {
  background-image: url(./image/agronomija.png) !important;
  background-position: 101% 60%;
  !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}

.zemes-ukio {
  background-image: url(./image/zemes-ukio.png) !important;
  background-position: 101% 60%;
  !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}

.maisto-kokybe {
  background-image: url(./image/maisto-tec.png) !important;
  background-position: 101% 60%;
  !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}

.avatar img {
  border-radius: 13px;
  margin-left: 14px;
}

.avatar {
  padding-left: 0px !important;
  width: 11% !important;
}

.panel-footer p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 24px;
}

.panel-body {
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0 !important;
  line-height: 2;
  text-align: justify;
}

.fb-icon {
  background-image: url('./image/fb-icon.png') !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.first-row {
  width: 50%;
}

.panel-footeris {
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
}

.panel-footer-text {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.panel-text {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.fb-area a {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.pasimatuok {
  margin: 5% 0 0px 18%;
  padding: 12px !important;
  background-color: #f8983a !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  border-top: 5px solid #f47834 !important;
}

.pasimatuok:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.registruokis:before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('./image/forma-1.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid #f47e35;
  border-radius: 31px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-position: center;
}

.pasimatuok-header:before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('./image/forma-2.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid #4ca366;
  border-radius: 31px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-position: center;
}

.pasirink:before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('./image/forma-3.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid #1e7693;
  border-radius: 31px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-position: center;
}

.paprasta {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.test {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.triangle:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("./image/triangle.png") no-repeat;
  width: 30px;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 26%;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.triangle-2:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("./image/triangle2.png") no-repeat;
  width: 30px;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 26%;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.test ul:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1e7693;
  width: 385px;
  /* half of limiter */
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.test ul:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f47e35;
  width: 385px;
  /* half of limiter */
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.test>ul:before {
  right: 0;
}

.test>ul:after {
  left: 0;
}

.test>ul {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.panel-group h1 {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  padding-top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel-body a {
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.panel-body a:after {
  content: "\203A";
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.panel-body a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.panel-heading a:after {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  content: "\2212";
  /* Plus */
  float: right;
  color: grey;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.panel-heading a.collapsed:after {
  content: "\2b";
  /* Minus */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <h1>Studijų programos</h1>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-header">
      <div class="panel-heading agronomija">

        <h4 class="panel-title studijos-title">

          <a class="collapsed accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
            Agronomija</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-header">
      <div class="panel-heading zemes-ukio">
        <h4 class="panel-title studijos-title">
          <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
              Žemės ūkio technologijos
              <span>ir vadyba</span>
            </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default ">
    <div class="panel-header">
      <div class="panel-heading maisto-kokybe">
        <h4 class="panel-title studijos-title">
          <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">
              Maisto žaliavų kokybė
              <span>ir sauga</span>
            </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Programa skirta parengti aukštos kvalifikacijos maisto žaliavų kokybės ir saugos specialistus, žinančius šių žaliavų įvairovę ir cheminę sudėtį, auginimo technologijas, gebančius analizuoti jų kokybinius pokyčius, turinčius darbo laboratorijoje
        įgūdžių, taikančius žinias profesinėje karjeroje. Studijuodamas išmoksi modeliuoti maisto žaliavų kokybę, identifikuoti ir analizuoti problemas, susijusias su maisto žaliavų laikymu, apdorojimu, suprasi maisto žaliavų kokybės ir saugos svarbą
        žmonių gyvenimo kokybei.
        <a href="#">Plačiau apie studijų programą</a>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footeris">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2 avatar">
            <img src="http://localhost/asu/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/demo-avatar.png"></div>
          <div class="col-md-6 panel-footer-text">
            <p class="panel-text">
              <strong>Kilo klausimų?</strong> Parašyk ASU studentui
            </p>
            <div class="fb-area">
              <span class="fb-icon"></span><a href="#">Vardas Pavardė</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="btn pasimatuok">Matuotis "profesija"</button>
          <div style="clear: both"></div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-header">
      <div class="panel-heading agronomija">
        <h4 class="panel-title studijos-title">
          <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse4">
                Agronomija
              </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-header">
      <div class="panel-heading zemes-ukio">
        <h4 class="panel-title studijos-title">
          <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse5">
                Žemės ūkio technologijos
                <span>ir vadyba</span>
              </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-header">
      <div class="panel-heading agronomija">
        <h4 class="panel-title studijos-title">
          <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse6">
                Agronomija
              </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-header">
      <div class="panel-heading zemes-ukio">
        <h4 class="panel-title studijos-title">
          <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse7">
                Žemės ūkio technologijos
                <span>ir vadyba</span>
              </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse7" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

During page load the accordions appeared with the **open** (or *minus*) sign because, it expects a bootstrap class `collapsed` in the `a` tag which has this attribute -> `data-toggle="collapse"`. The `collapsed` class has been missed in your code.

So it will look like:

```
<a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
                          Agronomija</a>
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/eqhaq8uf/)

Comment: can you add info about using classes, OP does not following the good practice.